# Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1 fails to publish to the local cluster, saying cluster instance is null

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I have go.ps1 file that establish connection to local service fabric cluster and then publish the app to it. The mind bending issue is when I run it the commands line by line in my powershell (admin elevated), they works. But if I run go.ps1 in the same elevated powershell, Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication fails saying the connection instance is null.

go.ps1 is like this.

```
Import-Module "$ENV:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1"
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster localhost:xxxxxx
Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication ...
```

go.ps1 succeeds up to Connect-ServiceFabricCluster localhost:xxxxxx, but fails with Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication ...

Yes, if I copy the commands and execute in my shell, they succeed without any problem. It's mind-boggling to me. Can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Do you run your script under administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes. I run the script under admin privilege

Comment: Can you update the questions with some output from the script?

Comment: Why don't you post the full script with the full error, might be easier to help you!